# How to use database function in Web API 2 with ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework database-first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I want to return int value from database so I am using a scalar function in the database in web api2 mvc 5 database first approach

```
[EdmFunction("talentStateModel.Store", "FN_Get_No_Leaves_Approved")]
public static int FN_Get_No_Leaves_Approved(string Academic_Year, int Leave_Type_ID, string Staff_Leave_ID)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calles are not supported");
}
```

Here I am passing parameters to above function from linq query, but getting NotSupportedException exception please any one can help. Thank you

Comment: Which "int value" do you want to get? What do you have? How does your database look like? Provide more info

Comment: I have function 'FN_Get_No_Leaves_Approved'  in database it will return number of staff leaves approved by manager. So i want to use this function in mvc5 entity framework database first approach/

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: if (leaveType.Any())
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(leaveType, n =>
                {
                    Staff_Leave objStaffLeave =new  Staff_Leave();                   
                    remainingLeaves = Convert.ToInt32(n.a.t.Staff_MaxLeave) - FN_Get_No_Leaves_Approved(n.a.t.Leave_Type_Master.Academic_Year, n.a.t.Leave_Type_Master.Leave_Type_ID, n.a.t.Staff_Leave_ID);
                    lst.Add(remainingLeaves);
                });
                return lst;
            } FN_Get_No_Leaves_Approved -is the function i am calling inside foreach loop

Comment: Take a look at this instructions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions.

You can use custom function only inside LINQ query, and not like a normal function.